# Open URL with a button inside a table view cell

Tags: ios, swift

I want to include a button in each table cell that opens a URL.

I've created tables (using an array) with images and labels just fine, however I'm confused how to create a button

Here's what I have so far

```
class ExploreCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var exploreImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var exploreTitleView: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var exploreDescriptionView: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var exploreButton: UIButton!

func setExplore(explore: Explore) {
    exploreImageView.image = explore.image
    exploreTitleView.text = explore.title
    exploreDescriptionView.text = explore.description
    exploreButton.addTarget(self, action: "connected:", for: .touchUpInside) = explore.button

}
```

My Class for the array looks like this

```
class ExploreListScreen: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var explores: [Explore] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    explores = createArray ()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

func createArray() -> [Explore] {

    var tempExplores: [Explore] = []

    let explore1 = Explore(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "test"), title: "Demo", description: "Essential", button: "")

    tempExplores.append(explore1)

    return tempExplores
}
```

Finally I have another file which contains the declared variables

```
class Explore {

var image: UIImage
var title: String
var description: String
var button: UIButton

init(image: UIImage, title: String, description: String, button: UIButton) {
    self.image = image
    self.title = title
    self.description = description
    self.button = button
}
```

Any advice and guidance would be fantastic. Thank-you!

Comment: You want to design button or navigate different url in button click

Comment: I want to navigate to a URL specified in the "createArray" function.

Comment: Go On this URL learn  about custom cell :) 
https://medium.com/@aapierce0/swift-using-protocols-to-add-custom-behavior-to-a-uitableviewcell-2c1f09610aa1

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I usually solve this. Create a delegate for your `UITableViewCell` subclass, and set the view controller owning the tableView as its delegate. Add methods for the interactions that happens inside the cell.

```
protocol YourTableViewCellDelegate: class {
    func customCellDidPressUrlButton(_ yourTableCell: YourTableViewCell)
}

class YourTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    weak var delegate: YourTableViewCellDelegate?

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        let button = UIButton()
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        addSubview(button)
    }

    required init?(coder _: NSCoder) {
        return nil
    }

    @objc func buttonTapped() {
        delegate?.customCellDidPressUrlButton(self)
    }

}
```

Then, in the controller, set itself as a delegate and get the indexPath trough the proper method, `indexPath(for:)`

```
class YourTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! YourTableViewCell
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
}

extension YourTableViewController: YourTableViewCellDelegate {
    func customCellDidPressUrlButton(_ yourTableCell: YourTableViewCell) {
        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: yourTableCell) else { return }
        print("Link button pressed at \(indexPath)")
    }
}
```

Then use that indexPath to grab the correct URL and present it from your table viewcontroller with a SFSafariViewController.

Answer (score -2):

**Swift 4**

This is best way to get `indexPath` using `touchPoint`

```
class YourTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // ...

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SwiftyCell", for: indexPath) as! SwiftyTableViewCell

        cell.label.text = "This is cell number \(indexPath.row)"

        // WRONG! When cells get reused, these actions will get added again! That's not what we want.
        // Of course, we could get around this by jumping through some hoops, but maybe there's a better solution...
        cell.yourButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.yourButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell
    }

    func yourButtonTapped(_ sender: Any?) {
        let point = tableView.convert(sender.center, from: sender.superview!)

        if let wantedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForItem(at: point) {
            let cell = tableView.cellForItem(at: wantedIndexPath) as! SwiftyCell

        }
    }
    // ...

}
```

[For more details you can follow this tutorials](https://medium.com/@aapierce0/swift-using-protocols-to-add-custom-behavior-to-a-uitableviewcell-2c1f09610aa1)

Comment: That's **a** way but not the best way 

Comment: What is the best possible way, would you please share i would really like to know more about this in details. Thanks

Comment: Please see my answer.

Comment: yes thats great but how can it be the best way? please explain it would be really great for me to learn something new

Answer (score -2):

Just create `UIButton` object in `viewDidLoad` and add this button as a sub view on cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function. Take Burton's frame as per your requirement.