# How to differentiate a button in a tableViewCell, being re-used in a tableView?

Tags: ios, swift

There are several sections in tableView. Each section has let say 9 rows. I have set a button in TableViewCell, which is visible only in 8th and 9th row of each section. And both of their functions are different, one is "delete" button, the other one is "make default" button. So how to differentiate the same button?

I have made a function let say `buttonTapped()` in TableViewCell class. I am using a custom button, in which I have declared a variable "indexPath", so as to differentiate the buttons. When I am configuring the cell, I am assigning indexPath.row to button's indexPath. So, for "delete" button indexPath becomes 7(8th row) and for "make default" it is 8(9th row). Then I have to switch over button's indexPath in `buttonTapped()` to achieve my target, with cases of 7 and 8. Is there any way to make this code generic, i.e. not hard coding 7 and 8 in cases.

```swift
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: CustomButton) {

        switch sender.indexPath {
        //Case 7 is 8th row in Table View
        case 7:
            //some code 
        //Case 8 is 9th row in Table View
        case 8:
            //some code
        default:
            break
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add and enum of possible actions that your button represents. e.g In your case it will be:

```
enum Actions {
case none
case delete
case makeDefault
}
```

In your CustomButton class you can add above enum variable rather than the index(row number) which is in your case 7 and 8. Than you can update your switch statement in buttonTapped function with this:

```
 @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: CustomButton) {
       switch sender.action {
            case .delete:
                //some code 
            case .makeDefault:
                //some code
            case .none:
                break
       }
  }
```

Now in your cell configuration function, you only have to set action type based on your data model (or some logic).

**Additional:**

I would also recommend to use delegate between your cell class and your view controller as mentioned above by @Rohit Makwana.

```
protocol CustomDelegate {
    func cellView(didPerformAction action: Actions onIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath)
}
```

By implementing this delegate in your view controller class, you can move your buttonTapped code in this method.

Comment: Thankyou @BilalAhmad. Enums do make the code more readable and generic.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using tag. As tag is an `Int` value, so if there is only one section, you may use `button.tag = indexPath.row` , but as having multiple section, you have to do tag as little bit different.

```
class CustomButton : UIButton {
    var tagIndexPath : IndexPath!

    // your rest of the code 
}
```

in cell class , where you set up your cell

```
/*** you may follow any of the procedures
// if you programitically create button
private lazy var button : CustomButton {
    let button = CustomButton()
    // your init of button 
    return button
}
// if you take outlet 
@IBOutlet weak var button : CustomButton!
***/

func setup(indexPath : IndexPath) {
     // initially button is hidden 
     button.isHidden = true 
     button.tagIndexPath = indexPath
     if indexPath.row == 7 || indexPath.row == 8 {
         button.isHidden = false 
     }
     button.addTarget(self, #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc private func buttonTapped() {
    switch self.button.tagIndexPath {
       case 7:
          // your work
       case 8:
          // your work
       default:
         print("Nothing to do")

    }
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, the cleanest and most native way to accomplish this is by using delegates. I described a solution to a very similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53760374/1278026

Comment: @OscarApeland The *cleanest and most native way* is a closure like in my answer.

Comment: @AnkurLahiry This solution fails reliably if cells can be moved, inserted or deleted.

Comment: @vadian Name one UIKit API that uses closures for user control interactions (bonus points if it's also prone to reference cycles like your answer)

Comment: @OscarApeland UIKit is not *native* because of its Objective-C legacy. And the closure in my answer doesn't cause a retain cycle.

Comment: @vadian I prefer to not go against the grain and follow the design of the framework I'm using. That's why I prefer using delegates, as it fits in with the rest of UIKit. Your answer doesn't cause issues in itself, but it's pretty likely that OP or future reader would call `self` in one of the case handlers and they might not be aware that they'll need to weaken the reference.

Comment: Thankyou @AnkurLahiry I appreciate your help, but if we do your way we're still hard coding the cases.

Comment: @AnkurLahiry Man, I didn’t realize my mistake until now. Posted this comment on mobile and intended to add it under the top level question. Sorry for the random discussion under your reply.

Comment: @OscarApeland, I never said your answer is wrong, but it is another way for solving the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Please Try this way to do.**

- **Custom Delegate**  // Make a custom Delegate

  ```
  protocol CustomDelegate {
      func buttonAction(WithIndexPath indexpath:IndexPath)
  }
  ```
- **TableView Cell**  // Your Custom TableView Cell

  ```
  class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

      @IBOutlet weak var yourButton: UIButton!

      var delegate : CustomDelegate?
      var indexPath: IndexPath?

      ... //Your code 

      @IBAction func customButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
         self.delegate?.buttonAction(WithIndexPath: self.indexPath!)
      }
  }
  ```
- **Your ViewController**

  ```
  class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CustomDelegate {

     @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         // Please register cell If you need
         self.tableView.delegate   = self
         self.tableView.dataSource = self
     }

     //MARK:- TableView Delegate And DataSource
     func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
         return 10 //As per your need
     }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         return 9 //As per your need
     }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell") as! CustomCell
         cell.delegate = self //Must
         cell.indexPath = indexPath //Must
         cell.yourButton.setTitle("\(indexPath.section) : \(indexPath.row)", for: .normal)
         return cell
       }

      //MARK:- Delegate Method of CustomDelegate
      func buttonAction(WithIndexPath indexpath: IndexPath) {

         //Customize as per your need.
         switch indexpath.row {
         case 7:
            break
         case 8:
            break
         default:
         print("Nothing to do")
       }
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: As well this solution doesn't work if cells can be moved, inserted or deleted.

Comment: You need to reload Tableview