# How to move curser from one textfield to another in a tableview Form in iOS?

Tags: swift

I have a Form that is to be made using a tableview. Each cell have a textfield and I want my cursor to move into next textfield when I tap "next" in keyboard.
here is the tableview code I m using currently:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.arrayData.count;
    }
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     let cell = tblView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellTextField")! as! cellTextField

            cell.tfValue.placeholder = objclsSignup.placeHolder! as String
            cell.tfValue.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.tfValue.delegate = self

             cell.tfValue.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.next
            if indexPath.row == 6 {
                cell.tfValue.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
            }
return cell
}


 func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
      if textField.returnKeyType == UIReturnKeyType.next{
textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}else {
textField.resignFirstResponder()
}
return true 
}
```

I am using swift 4, Xcode 10.2.

Comment: use this for ur tableview: https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Comment: Please read something like [this](https://github.com/linkedin/swift-style-guide#2-naming) style guide, it will make more people want to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, instead of passing data with tags, use delegates in the cell like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53758873/open-url-with-a-button-inside-a-table-view-cell/53760374#53760374).

When you have a delegate that passes the cell up to your data source/delegate, use the indexPath to grab the next cell (if any) and use the function `becomeFirstResponder()`on your `UITextField` to focus it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code set delegate to textField in Storyboard..

```
extension LoginPageViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == userNameTextField {
        userNameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        emailTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else if textField == emailTextField {
        emailTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        passwordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else {
        performYourAction()
    }

    return true
}
```